# Two libstdc++.so.6 files and version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found error

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, libstdc++

I have Ubuntu 15.10 with GCC 5.2.1 and Qt 5.5.1.
When I try to run my Qt application, I get this error:

> ~/Qt/builds/gvis-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/app/gvis: ~/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found

`strings` command shows that `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` file has `GLIBCXX_3.4.21` and `~/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libstdc++.so.6` hasn't.

I tried to replace qt libstdc++.so file with system one but got a lot of errors in runtime.

Why there are another libstdc++.so file in Qt SDK directory? And how to get my app running again? It worked well on Ubuntu 15.04.

(Please don't tell me that I should downgrade my Ubuntu or Qt SDK)

Comment: What are you compiling your code with? I encounter more or less the same problem when I try to compile with a custom local install of GCC, whereas I do not when compiling with standard GCC from the repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt SDK reinstall fixed the error.
The fresh Qt SDK do not contains libstdc++.so file and everything is working well.